# Con cable a un repetidor wifi, es lo mismo que si estuviera conectado al cable de red original?

Tags: wifi

Me exigen para teletrabajar conexión por cable directamente al equipo. Mi pregunta es, si instalo un repetidor wifi, y de este al equipo,un cable ?,sería lo mismo que  si lo tengo conectado directamente por el cable original de red ???
Gracias !

Comment: Creo entender que te piden conexión por cable por la "estabilidad" de la conexión, no es lo mismo si lo haces como mencionas ya que el medio de transmisión desde el origen principal (router) hacia el repetidor sigue siendo wi-fi. Saludos.

Comment: Nacho. No creo que sea este el foro apropiado para esta pregunta. Tal vez quieras preguntar en los foros de los fabricantes. Para ayudarte, te debo decir que no sería exactamente lo mismo. Tu conexión será tan rápida como la comunicación entre el repeater y el módem.

Comment: Voto por cerrar la pregunta porque no tiene nada que ver con temas de programación.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no versa sobre la temática del sitio, leer [ask]

Comment: Gracias @JosueArriola.

Comment: No tenía muy claro si estos temas también se exponían aquí @Bicho, vota vota que para eso estamos en democracia. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Dado que es una cuestión de las condiciones de trabajo, lo normal es que preguntes a tu trabajo. Si aquí te decimos que sí y ellos te dicen que no, la respuesta que vale es la suya. Si deciden sancionarte por violar la política de seguridad de la empresa, por ejemplo, decir "es que Franklin Parra de SOe me dijo que podía" no te librará de la sanción.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Sip, aunque lo puede variar un poco es la Velocidad ya que dependes tanto de la señal del repetidor como del equipo en sí, si trabaja a 100 o 1000mbps.

Lo que puede variar es si te conectas por Wifi o Cable, ya que ambos tienen configuración IP diferente y quizás pueda inferir (depende del contexto). Pero si necesitan que estés conectado a la red por LAN, es una alternativa extenderlo con un Repetidor y conectar la PC por LAN.

Editado:
Obviamente hay muchas comillas, restricciones, limitaciones y variaciones en cuanto al contexto, pero puede funcionar y es posible ya que recibe la conexión por LAN mediante el repetidor de la misma red.

Comment: No se te olviden las configuraciones del "Port Forwarding"

Comment: Por favor evita responder a preguntas basadas en opiniones; en este caso es una pregunta fuera de temas de programación y que sería manejada mejor en Stack Exchange.

Comment: La verdad es que no tienes ni idea de porqué han puesto esta restricción, así que no tienes ni idea si un repetidor cumpliría con las restricciones que marca la empresa.

Comment: Basado en el contexto, y ya que solo necesita estar conectado por cable; se puede responder que si. ya que sigue estando dentro de la misma Red y conectado por cable(que es lo que piden), en el caso de que marque otras excepciones o necesidades la respuesta no sería la misma, Quizás solo sea para rastrear la PC por la IP del LAN, pero como hay muchas opciones abiertas me baso en responder en el contexto simple.

Comment: El tema es que la pregunta está fuera del alcance del sitio y como notas termino cerrada y tú con varios negativos

Comment: si, justo me acabo de dar cuenta. Lo que no tengo presente son las normativas del foro, quizás uno mas experimentado se percate con mayor facilidad.  Aunque me causa gracia que ignorante del tema me lleve todos esos negativos :D  Gracias por notificar igual

Comment: Realiza el [tour] y revisa  [answer]

Comment: Respecto al comentario de SJuan76, si ya entiendo el problema. Se agradece a todos la paciencia de explicar la situación y el problema en si.